# ionic vs material design vs tabris, or vs other frameworks

Tags: android, ios, mobile, frameworks, cross-platform

I have basic knowledge about js/html/css

recently I learned angularJs, which is pretty cool!

for those cross platform mobile development, not sure which one is good for newbies?

Answer (score 2):

ionic. Because you know angularjs, html, css, js, you got all you need for ionic.

All right, You are right @Abubakr Dar I need give more elaborate answer.

## First, Ionic is simple.

http://ionicframework.com/getting-started/

How to build your first app?

```
npm install -g cordova ionic
ionic start myApp tabs/blank/sidemenu
cd myApp
ionic platform add ios/android
ionic build ios/android
ionic emulate ios/android
```

Then you got you own app. It's really simple.

## Second, one code, both android and ios.

Your code can easily runs on android or ios, this is amazying.

You don not need to lean fragment in android or other someting in ios. just angularjs , you can build both android app and ios app.

## Third, coding and deal with styles is very very convenient.

just

```
ionic serve
```

then you can preview your app on browser, as soon as you save your code, browser auto refresh and show what you just done, so light! so fast!

Find style wrong? you can fix the style with Chrome F12 or firebug or IE'
s something hahahahahaha. (You know CSS? Give half an hour to learn SASS, good for you.)

When you deal with Java code android project, you want to see is the style right, you need wait minutes for building and deploy. Ionic , just need save you code.(Chrome has Toggle device mode good for you)

## Others

Angularjs so convenient, and lot's of AngularJS module you can use in ionic (such as : http://crisbeto.github.io/angular-svg-round-progressbar/)

ton's of ionic samples on internet.

Comment: You need to give more elaborate answer.